# Just out of curiosity, can console.log() send a console command?

Tags: console

Can `console.log()` send an executable command to the Console? Such as, `console.log('pwd')`? Or is there some other method for sending Console commands from the webpage?

FYI: This is not an XY problem. I am just curious.

Comment: Which console do you mean? Do you want to send messages from the browser to a (which?) operating system shell? I would _hope_ that this is not possible.

Comment: I was referring to the Chrome console developer tool. Without developer mode on.

Comment: I may need to research some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. If it would be possible, the website could run actual programs on your computer which would be a huge security issue.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now that I think about it. The reason I asked is because I noticed that you can write "alert()" to the console but I didn't know 100% if those messages could be written in other languages and still be executable.